# How to skip a number of lines when writing to a txt file

Tags: java

I'm making a program that will output lines to a text file. I don't wish to overwrite the file, but that is what my current code does. I just want to go down the number of lines that are already there and write `hello`. Here is my code:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileLocation, false);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

while(numberOfLines > compareToNumOfLines) {
    bufferedWriter.newLine();
    compareToNumOfLines++;
}

bufferedWriter.write("hello");
bufferedWriter.close();
```

Unfortunately, this just creates spaces where the text used to be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that file systems in general do not support editing files in random places; you can't go to line number N and for example insert a new line there (or overwrite existing line N). You can, however, append data to the end of an existing file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileLocation, false);
```

to

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileLocation, true);
```

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), the second argument is a boolean that specify if you want to append the text or overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append text to existing file then open the file in append mode. If you want to write at random place in file then you can use RandomAccessFile class.